# Using Class Probabilities from Random Forest to do Ranking

Tags: random-forest, ranking

Assume that we have set of documents which are being labelled as relevant and non-relevant. Can I used the class probabilities generated by Random Forest in python scikit-learn to rank the documents based on the probabilities?

```
#generate synthetic data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4, n_informative=2, n_redundant=0, random_state=0, shuffle=False)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

predictions = clf.predict_proba([[0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 7, 5, 2]])
print(predictions)
```

Assume the example above which I have two documents, where each document has four features. The probabilities generated by RF will be as follow:

```
[0.14297294 0.85702706]
[0.29163087 0.70836913]
```

The left column is probabilities for relevant and the right column is probabilities for irrelevant. I plan to used the probability score on the left column to rank the documents accordingly. Is it the right way to do ranking with Random Forest?

Comment: what do you mean by ranking? Are you ranking them according to how likely they are to belong to the relevant class? If so, then yes, this would be right.

Comment: if i want to rank it so that the most relevant documents appear on top, is that possible?

Comment: The correct interpretation is probably not that you are ranking it so that the most relevant documents appear on top, but rather that "the documents with the highest probability of being relevant" appear on top. If you want the most relevant ones to appear on top, you need to set this up as a regression problem, in which every document is not ranked as "relevant" or "not relevant" (binary) but has somehow been labelled according to "how relevant" it is

Comment: have we have a binary classification problem (e.g. 1-relevant, 0-non-relevant) and work on the ranking?

Comment: If you are only giving your algorithm information on whether a document is relevant or not, and not telling it "how relevant" it is, then it can't learn this. All it can do is return documents that it has higher confidence are relevant. Of the top 100 most likely to be relevant, you would expect a higher fraction to be judged as relevant by a human, than the next 100 down, and so forth